# Need help getting images to display in HTML and SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am really new to HTML and CSS (SCSS in this case), and am having issues getting an Image to display properly on a localhost page I have been experimenting on. I will post my HTML lines, as well as my SCSS lines below. Maybe you guys can tell me what I am doing wrong so I can move ahead.

I have tried linking just the project folder directory path, all the way up to the WHOLE path through my computer to the image. I have quadruple checked the names on the files and the image as well. I believe it is probably just a Syntax error.

```
<!--HTML LINES:-->

<div id="Center.Logo">
<img src="sberube-portfolio-site-f29e4e843dc2\src\app\home\home\home.component.images\center-logo.png"
alt="Center Circle" style=" width: 250px; height: 250px;"> <!--Desired image -->
</div>

/* SCSS LINES: */

 #Center.Logo {
            img{
                margin: auto;
                align-content: center;
            }
        }
```

I expect the image to display in the CENTER of the page, instead, it simply gives me the ALT tag next to a little picture icon on the  bottom left of the page.

Comment: P.S. the uncapitalized #center tag in the SCSS has been adjusted to capital to no effect.

Comment: hi NotJayson, welcome to stackoverflow. can you post your directory structure? like where the scss will be end up compiled to and where the image is?

Comment: @BagusTesa I can post the general directory structure to the SCSS and Image files, however, I am unsure as to where the SCSS would exactly be compiled to. Here is the directory path for the SCSS :C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\Repo-1\MEAN-Expirimental\sberube-portfolio-site-f29e4e843dc2\src\app\home\home\home.component.scss //// and the path for the Image : C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\Repo-1\MEAN-Expirimental\sberube-portfolio-site-f29e4e843dc2\src\app\home\home\home.component.images\center-logo.png

Comment: IIRC, `img` tags only allow slashes (`/`) to be used to indicate new paths instead of backward slashes (`\`).

Comment: @Edric I changed the ( \ )'s to ( / )'s and it did nothing.

Comment: Please attach an image to this question with a screenshot of your filestructure. I.e. Where your image is + another one for wherever the .HTML file is that contains the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector should be `#Center.Logo` in your code it's look like `#center.Logo`

And if you want looks like it centered try [this](https://codepen.io/Shuree/pen/BaaRPjL)

And if you can't getting images  try working around with your project structure.

`<img src="../assets/img/centered-logo.jpg">` etc not whole path or something.

Comment: I commented on my own post clarifying that both tags do in fact have Capital C's, I just miss-typed, and even so it has the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Can you give a look of the project structure ?

Comment: Additional help didn't work, even with your revised syntax for the HTML, and SCSS. I should add, I am using Visual Studio Code, with an Angular CLI pluggin running to serve my Localhost page. If that means anything.

Comment: Your projects in angular ?

Comment: I replied to Bagus Tesa with pathing for the SCSS and the Image.

Comment: Not technically. It uses Angular CLI to link the SCSS and the HTML as well as allot of other Project aspects together without explicit link references. I would explain more, but I am following suite with a Lead Stack Dev who set me up with this environment. The core work I am doing, is in HTML and SCSS right now. That is what you are seeing in the question.

Comment: can you post a image of your project structure ?

Comment: I assume you mean like a whole screenshot of the project, and its files correct?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E0Tpf-AQy7QL9DoY0BDB2-G44MP0fDSz/view?usp=sharing   Here is a picture

Comment: just put `<img src="./home.component.images/center-logo.png">`

Comment: Still nothing. Maybe I am having some sort of glitch here. I appreciate the help all the same.

Comment: Have you tried something like `../../home.component.images/center-logo.png` yet? or `../home.component.images/center-logo.png` ?

Comment: @EGC I have tried just about every pathing for the Image file, yet nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is you use a dot inside the name of your id.
This is a problem, since in css the dot is part of a class selector.

The Rule `#CSS.Logo {...}` applies to an element that has both, an id of 'CSS' and a class of 'Logo'. Something like this:

```
<div id="CSS" class="Logo">
    ...
</div>
```

There is no element like that in your code, so the css rules are not applied.

Second, your original css code is not suitable to center an image within another container.

```
// This is your original code as you posted it:
img {
    margin: auto;
    align-content: center;
}
```

The rule align-content is only applicable in a flex box container. You could however use margins to center the image horizontally like this:

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What you probably want instead is this:

```
<div id="center-logo">
  <img src="your-image.png" alt="Center Circle">
</div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0; // making sure you have the whole page at your disposal
}

#center-logo {
  height: 100vh; // using the full height of the viewport

  // this is where the actual centering happens:
  display: flex; // this is necessary for the following 3 rules (flex box)
  flex-flow: row nowrap; // in this case this could also be column nowrap
  align-items: center; // vertical center
  justify-content: center; // horizontal center

  img {
  // set a width and height so the image does not stretch and to avoid repositioning
  // the image (or other content if there is any) as soon as the image has been loaded
    width: 250px; 
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

Notice I have used small letters for the id name, because it usually helps avoiding issues caused by misspelling the names afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it is a regular html and css.

You can compile with node.

```
npm init
npm install node-sass
```

Add this to your package.json (in scripts)

`"scss": "node-sass --watch scss -o css"`

Create two Folders.

CSS and SCSS.
Inside each one, the file style. (With the right termination)
css> style.css eg

and finally

```
npm run scss
```

Everything you type in scss, it converts to css.